# O que é mais rápido, acessar dados em arquivo ou banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, json, arquivo

Em questão de performance qual método é mais veloz para se recuperar dados, 1) ler um arquivo (que será gerado apenas uma vez com o PHP) ou 2) pegar esses dados de um banco de dados?

Esses dados serão sempre mostrados na página em questão. Até o momento estou usando um arquivo `.json` e lendo os arquivos de lá, mas pensei na possibilidade de se fazer isso tudo diretamente com um banco de dados.

Comment: Na minha opinião você deve primeiro fazer uma balanceamento! Tens que ver qual tipo pra você é mais útil, pois nem sempre o mais rápido é o melhor para se trabalhar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depende da intenção. Me parece pela descrição que o arquivo é mais negócio. Se for exatamente como você disse.

Mas tem quem goste de por tudo em banco de dados, pelo menos em SQLite. Alguns preferem por em um banco de dados se já está usando um para outras coisas. Isso pode ser útil para facilitar *backup* replicação, segurança de acesso, etc. Evidentemente se você sabe que todos seus dados estão em um só lugar ajuda a organização. Mas se tiver todos arquivos extras necessários em um só lugar também não vai criar muito problema. É comum colocar no banco de dados porque já está acostumado manipulá-lo, já tem funções que acessam facilmente o DB.

A performance de acesso à arquivo direto é maior. Mas a velocidade do banco de dados é tão rápida também que não faz muita diferença. Se você não tem que ficar gravando nada neste arquivo principalmente de forma concorrente, pode usá-lo sem problemas. Mas a questão é se vai dar mais trabalho fazer um acesso de forma diferente.

Se não tem um problema real de performance, confiabilidade ou coisa parecida, é mais uma questão de gosto.

Não vejo nem vantagens nem desvantagens claras nas duas abordagens, repito, no caso descrito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

O mais rápido nem sempre é o melhor para sua aplicação.

Geralmente, quando se trata de recuperação de dados, é recomendável usar o banco de dados.

Em um banco de dados você pode selecionar o registro que quer ler, já um arquivo isso é mais difícil.

É claro que tudo isso depende do caso de uso. Eu não usaria, por exemplo, o banco de dados para salvar dados de conexão webservice do meu sistema. Eu poderia fazer isso em um arquivo de configuração simplesmente.

Como foi dito em um comentário, você tem que fazer um balanceamento para saber qual dos dois atende mais à necessidade.

Preocupar demais com performance as vezes pode ser mais prejudicial do que  benéfico. Concordo plenamente com a "doutrina do equilíbrio" nesse caso.

Agora, não digo que devemos ignorá-la totalmente (a performance). Se for utilizar banco de dados, você deverá fazer os procedimentos corretos para que o mesmo não se torne um peso para o sistema (falo de queries mal construídas, falta de índices).

No fim, não creio que seja conveniente fazer comparações entre os dois modos, já que cada um depende de como e em que você vai aplicar. Se não se torna a mesma discussão de **POO vs programação procedural**.

Comment: Tá dificil a vida aqui no SOPT

Comment: Na verdade a resposta era bem mais simples do que parece - **portabilidade** da informação gerada e reutilizada e **segurança** para os diferentes ambientes - vezes em que não há exigências de uma nem outra utiliza-se o que melhor servir.

Answer (score -2):

as structures do c e as UDT do visual basic se traduzem em um campo binário de valor fixo que podem ser lidos e escritos em arquivos.
tanto em suas formas randomica ou sequencial podem ler do primeiro registro ao último de forma infinitamente mais rápida que qualquer sistema sql existente.
é a forma mais rápida e eficiente de ler/gravar dados