# Quais as vantagens de se utilizar um banco de dados ao invés de um arquivo JSON para gravar dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, independente-de-linguagem

A maioria dos sistemas, atualmente, utiliza o recurso de banco de dados para gravar os mais diversos tipos de informações, até mesmo informações estáticas. Isso leva a conclusão de que um banco de dados traz conveniências significantes.

Quais as vantagens da utilização de um banco de dados em contraste com uma forma mais simples de gravação de dados como, por exemplo, um arquivo JSON ou XML?

Note que não estou perguntando o que é "melhor". Sei que cada forma de fazer as coisas (em sua maioria, pelo menos) possui suas vantagens e desvantagens. É por isso que estou perguntando a respeito das vantagens de um banco de dados no contexto especificado. Com isso, também não estou pedindo opiniões, já que acredito que esse tipo de pergunta possa ser respondido com fatos, como [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113899/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-vantagens-de-utilizar-banco-de-dados-orientado-a-objetos) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452607/o-que-%C3%A9-um-monorepo-quais-s%C3%A3o-as-suas-vantagens-e-desvantagens).

Já verifiquei também algumas outras questões aqui no SOpt, mas não encontrei a resposta desejada:

- [Posso usar um arquivo JSON como banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295762/posso-usar-um-arquivo-json-como-banco-de-dados)

  Nessa as respostas dizem como fazer, mas não *por que* ou *por que não* fazer.
- [É uma boa ideia usar JSON como database?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324271/%C3%89-uma-boa-ideia-usar-json-como-database)

  Já nessa as respostas mostram que JSON é apenas um formato de dados, e não uma base de dados, e também sugerem alternativas a um banco de dados convencional. No entanto, as vantagens de armazenar dados em uma base de dados ao invés de em *um arquivo `.JSON`* (não confundir com *formato JSON*) não são apresentadas claramente.
- [O que é mais rápido, acessar dados em arquivo ou banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45423/o-que-%C3%A9-mais-r%C3%A1pido-acessar-dados-em-arquivo-ou-banco-de-dados)

  Essa pergunta é focada apenas em velocidade e performance da obtenção de dados.

Para diminuir as chances de alguém achar que a pergunta é aberta demais, vamos a um exemplo simples.

Suponhamos que tenho uma aplicação web de tarefas. As informações a serem guardadas em uma base de dados ou arquivo JSON seriam as de autenticação de usuário, além de informações a respeito de tarefas, estatísticas e configurações de cada um deles. Trata-se de uma aplicação que poderia vir a servir um grande número de usuários, realizando diversas operações CRUD. Faço novamente a pergunta do título voltada a uma situação como essa.

Artigos/perguntas relacionadas também são bem-vindos.

Comment: Como assim comparar um SGDB com um formato de arquivo? A responsabilidade do SGDB é gerenciar a persistência, a manipulação, consistência e a organização dos dados, assim como controlar o acesso aos dados gerir a concorrência do acesso aos dados. Enquanto responsabilidade do formato JSON é apenas ser um padrão de troca de dados simples e rápida entre sistemas. Um você usa para guardar/acessar os dados o outro usa para comunicar os dados.

Comment: Um a parte no que gera confusão, Bancos de dados NoSQL orientados a documentos usam formatos de documentos similares a XML , YAML , JSON porém o que não é difundido é que esses documentos são suportados dentro do banco de dados NoSql como uma estrutura de metadados criando um modelo de objetos para cada documento armazenado, assim dando a impressão ao usuário de estar consultando simples documentos JSON, por exemplo, quando na verdade o que está sendo consultado é uma estrutura de dados muito mais complexa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um [banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191199/101) foi feito para armazenar dados, isso por si só deve ser vantagem suficiente para pensar em adotá-lo.

Pode pensar que JSON também serve para armazenar dados, mas não, e isso já foi respondido antes, conforme sabe. Você pode usar o JSON onde quiser, até dentro de um banco de dados, mas não foi feito para armazenar dados.

Mas dá para pegar então a comparação certa que é entre armazenar dados em um banco de dados e armazenar dados em um arquivo, por acaso em formato JSON.

Um banco de dados é uma ferramenta de software onde você pede para armazenar, acessar e manipular dados. Um arquivo, seja que formato for, é só isso, o seu programa tem que manipular isto. É problema seu cuidar de tudo em todas essas operações.

O banco de dados te dá mais garantias, mais facilidade, e eficiência, conforme já sabido. Claro que cada DB específico dará mais ou menos, mas em geral a maioria dará muito.

A vantagem do arquivo em JSON é ser muito simples de manipular não exigindo um software sofisticado instalado ou indo junto. Manipular o arquivo JSON provavelmente exigirá uma biblioteca para manupulá-lo (dá para fazer totalmente na mão, são poucos que o farão por um motivo ou outro), mas será algo simples. Fora isso ainda pode ocupar um espaço menor quando a informação for muito pequena.

Quando está falando de armazenar configurações ou dados que praticamente não são manipulados pode ser mais prático que um DB, mas até isso se questiona um pouco. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159484/101).

Até pode ser um arquivo de *log*, ainda que o formato JSON pode não ser o mais adequado. Mas tudo para aí. Por isso é até complicado falar nas vantagens do DB, porque são todas possíveis menos a citada no parágrafo anterior.

Mesmo coisas simples já começa compensar usar um DB simples e pequeno como o SQLite ou outro mais simples ainda.

Note que eu nem estou comprando apenas com um DB relacional e principalmente que tem SQL como linguagem de acesso aos dados, isso tudo pode ser vantagens específicas de um tipo de banco de dados.

Se você tiver acesso vindo de fonte externa e/ou concorrente tem todo esforço para isso ocorrer de forma adequada dentro do DB e não é você que precisa codificar, o que seria uma tortura e sairia errado, poucas pessoas são capazes de fazer isso bem. Em um volume grande de acesso a pessoa só consegue fazer acontecer se praticamente ela escrever um software de banco de dados dentro da aplicação dela.

Um banco de dados dá várias formas de acessar o dado de forma eficiente, ele não é só um local para armazenar dados, mas principalmente recuperá-los, geralmente através de índices. Só de você não ter que pensar nisso já é uma enorme vantagem. Se for fazer algo assim nesse arquivo JSON terá que pelo menos pensar como cuidará de toda manipulação. Se não é só ler algo pequeno então é algo bem difícil de fazer.

Nem falei ainda na segurança, até porque existem diversos níveis que pode ter em cada DB.

Também não falei de consistência porque nem todos do *databases* oferecem isso muito bem. Não por acaso alguns dos que não oferecem são os que optaram por ter o formato JSON internamente.

Na verdade só consigo imaginar duas razões para uma pessoa escolher usar um arquivo JSON como banco de dados: ela não quer aprender usar um banco de dados (que parece mais complicado no primeiro momento, mas quando ela for manipular um arquivo na mão ela verá o engano que cometeu e como era mais fácil); ou ela quer fazer graça.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Ao manipular o arquivo JSON, ele deverá ser carregado na memória e só então o tratamento dos dados é realizado.

Agora, imagine uma base de dados de 100 gigabytes ou mais. Quanta memória seu servidor teria que ter?

Bases de dados relacionais ou orientadas a objetos possuem índices para organizar os dados e tornar possível extrair dados mesmo que estas tenham terabytes de informação.

JSON serve apenas para enviar alguns dados de um local a outro, é apenas um XML repaginado.

Agora eu pergunto, o que exige mais desempenho do servidor? Eu testei, aqui está o resultado.

http://sqlui.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que a resposta para essa pergunta passa pela classificação dos dados de acordo com sua relação no diagrama de sistema:

```
           .---------.
Entrada -> | Sistema | -> Saída
   ^       '---------'      |
   '------------------------'
```

1. *apenas entrada*, como constantes, imagens, strings de tradução de mensagens, e configurações de execução;
2. *apenas saída*, como logs de execução, processamentos de linha de comando, e dados que se espera ser consumido por outro sistema;
3. *entrada e saída*, como dados dinâmicos de usuário, dados mutáveis de negócio, e outros que podem ser escritos e lidos.

Um arquivo, no formato JSON ou não, tem como principal vantagem ser *legível* e *editável*, não só por humanos como também por ferramentas que operam linha-a-linha, como Git e todo o ferramental Unix. Em geral, eles também são simples de *gerar* de dentro de um sistema. Por esse motivo, **arquivos** encaixam-se bem com dados que se encaixam nas classificações (1) e (2) acima. Alguns tipos de entrada são tão estáticos que até adicionamos ao código do sistema!

O problema de arquivos, contudo, é sua robustez. De certo modo, eles são uma solução de baixo nível. O sistema de arquivos pode não ser confiável, como em um sistema montado em rede; podem existir problemas de alteração concorrente por diferentes processos; e o modelo de um arquivo é apenas uma fileira de bytes sequenciais, que é pouco expressiva para modelos mais complexos de dados.

(É interessante que o SQLite diz que pode [substituir o `fopen()`](https://sqlite.org/about.html), porque eles já superaram todos esses problemas ao escrever uma engine de banco de dados. Eles dizem que até conseguem escrever em um arquivo [mais rápido do que com `fwrite()`](https://sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)!)

Para aumentar a robustez da sua aplicação, então, é que se recomenda utilizar um banco de dados nos casos (3). Seria possível driblar alguns problemas de arquivos, como falha durante a escrita, ou realizar escrita incremental, ou usar um arquivo de checkpoint... mas tudo isso já é suportado por bancos de dados.

Note que não tratei aqui sobre os dados serem estruturados ou em tabelas. De certo modo, dados estruturados se alinham mais a arquivos livres de esquema, enquanto dados em tabelas mapeiam lindamente para todo tipo de banco de dados. Contudo, acredito que o principal ponto é sobre padrão de acesso: dados tabulares podem ser escritos como múltiplos arquivos CSV, e dados hierárquicos podem ser guardados em bancos NoSQL, ou armazenados como blobs em bancos relacionais.